# Are the HCI commands of Bluetooth, standard or vendor specific?

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-hci

I've seen various command formats for Bluetooth operation in accordance with the HCI.  Does the HCI commands of Bluetooth changes from Vendor to Vendor or constant to all vendors?

Comment: HCI is standard except just few. Refer to Bluetooth core specification that describes all HCI commands.

Answer (score 0):

HCI commands are part of Bluetooth specifications. Those can be found on:
www.bluetooth.com

So basically all HCI commands specified there must be supported by vendor to be approved by the Bluetooth organization.

However, it's not prohibited for a vendor to add his own specific commands which are not part of the specification.